# How to obtain APP_ID and CLIENT_KEY for Parse server hosted on a EC2 of AWS

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, parse-server

I am really new to `AWS` and `EC2`, and I am trying to hook my `Android` project with my new `Parse` server hosted on my `EC2` instance but in order to initialize my server in my project, I need my APP_ID and CLIENT_KEY which for some silly reason I cannot find them.

Here is what I have done till now:

- I am **Not** using a `Java` SSH Client since It doesn't working! Instead I am using the alternative which is a **standalone** SSH client
- Connected to bitnami parse server via my terminal (Mac), with success.
- I obtained my username and password and I have access to my Parse dashboard.

Most suggestions I came across, where giving solutions based on a Java SSH client via Browser connection, but like I said, I am using the Standalone one. So how do I obtain it??

Here is my code:

```
 Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(getApplicationContext())

        //where do I Find my APP_ID
        .applicationId("myappid")

        //where do I Find my CLIENT_KEY
        .clientKey(null)

        .server("http://ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/parse/")
        .build()
);


ParseObject object = new ParseObject("ExampleObject");
object.put("myNumber", "123");
object.put("myString", "rob");

object.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback () {
  @Override
  public void done(ParseException ex) {
    if (ex == null) {
      Log.i("Parse Result", "Successful!");
    } else {
      Log.i("Parse Result", "Failed" + ex.toString());
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: have you created new application on your parse server?

Comment: @FahedYasin yes I have an app in the dashboard

Answer (score 2):

Turnes out all I had to do was to open the server.js file on the Bitnami parse server running in my terminal. And that's achieved by doing the following (In the Bitnami parse server in Terminal):

```
cd /opt/bitnami/apps/parse/htdocs/
```

and then:

```
vi server.js
```

Answer (score 2):

This problem usually occurs while using `putty` in Windows 10, so if you want to open the `server.js` file in the terminal, you have to run the following commands:

```
cd stack/parse
cat config.json
```

And if you want to know your username and password for logging in Parse Dashboard, you have to run the following command:

```
cat /home/bitnami/bitnami_credentials
```

Here is the link where you can check all the commands that are mentioned above int the console:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

just run this below command

```
ssh -i <your pem file with path> <your public DNS>
```

for example

```
sudo ssh -i "Downloads/karthi.pem" ubuntu@ec2-1821-434-234-5130.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same problem while using PuTTY on my Windows 10. Then I posted this issue on Udemy platform of my course. There Rob (Tutor of course) replied with the following way.

cd stack/parse

cat config.json

Hope this works for you too.[the following link is the code how it worked for me. Check it if you want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmKPL.png)