# How to get application ID from parse server? I cannot find the file "Server.js"

Tags: android, amazon-ec2, ssh, putty, parse-server

First of all, I thank this community for building such a great place for resources.

This is my first question since I opened my account a few days ago. I just started to learn Android development and for a project from the tutorial I'm following, I need to set up "Parse Server" on an instance of AWS EC2 and get "**Application ID and Client Key from the file "Server.js" located at "apps/parse/htdocs/"**.

**I was able to SSH connect to server using putty, but I'm not able to go to that directory(apps/parse/htdocs/) I've ran a find command got multiple files named "Server.js" but wasn't able to find the right file.**

I've searched and found previous questions and answers [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50119158/how-to-obtain-app-id-and-client-key-for-parse-server-hosted-on-a-ec2-of-aws) which didn't help me in my particular case.
I logged in as user "bitnami" and also searched for that file as root, but no luck.

Am I missing something? I've spent over 3 hours on this with zero progress, but I don't want to give up. Please point me in right direction in getting that info. Thank you in advance.

Screenshot attached for reference of the errors I got vs the screenshot of tutorial

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0sHe.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent some time and learned that they've updated both location and the file name in recent version. For anyone who's in similar situation, you can find the required info at below location.

/opt/bitnami/parse/config.json/

source: https://community.bitnami.com/t/unable-to-find-opt-bitnami-apps-parse-htdocs-server-js/78200/19

Comment: This helped me. Thanks!